# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka - How to handle exceptions in batch mode

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

For my kafka batch consumer there are two types of situations I would like to handle.

1. Deserialization exceptions that occur before the listener has received the records. Not much point retrying these, just send straight to DLQ.
2. Exceptions that occur within the listener. As I am applying some streaming operations on the batch (filtering and grouping etc) it would be difficult to know exactly which record in the batch failed. So it's simpler and acceptable for me to just retry the whole batch and if the retry limit is reached send the full batch to the DLQ.

---

### Edited after feedback

I have been able to successfully use a ListenerContainerCustomizer to solve scenario 2.

Now I still need to handle scenario 1 (deserialization exceptions).
I have tried using a failedDeserializationFunction as described here https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.12.RELEASE/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer

```
@Getter
public class BadRequestEvent extends RequestEvent {

    private final FailedDeserializationInfo failedDeserializationInfo;

    public BadRequestEvent(FailedDeserializationInfo failedDeserializationInfo) {
        this.failedDeserializationInfo = failedDeserializationInfo;
    }

}

public class FailedRequestEventProvider implements Function<FailedDeserializationInfo, RequestEvent> {

    @Override
    public RequestEvent apply(FailedDeserializationInfo info) {
        return new BadRequestEvent(info);
    }

}
```

Config

```
spring:
  kafka.consumer.properties:
        value.deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
        key.deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
        spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer
        spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
        spring.deserializer.value.function: com.consumer.domain.event.FailedRequestEventProvider
        spring.json.value.default.type: com.consumer.domain.event.RequestEvent
 cloud.stream:
  kafka:
    binder:
      brokers:
       - broker1:9092
       - broker2:9092
       - broker3:9092
       - broker4:9092
  function:
    definition: receive
  bindings:
    receive-in-0:
      destination: RequestEvent
      group: requestConsumer
      consumer:
        batch-mode: true
```

I can see the in the consumer that BadRequestEvent is being build correctly and indeed contains FailedDeserializationInfo. But when this is finally sent to the listener it is being serilaized back into RequestEvent and the information is lost.

Seems like I'm missing something here. I was under the impression the listener would receive a list of BadRequestEvents and RequestEvents? These could then be handled as necessary

Answer (score 1):

Spring cloud stream does not use the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` from Boot; to configure the error handler, you need to add a `ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory>` bean instead.

The best solution is the [RecoveringBatchErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#recovering-batch-eh) where you throw a `BatchListenerFailedException` to tell the error handler which record failed.

There is also the [RetryingBatchErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retrying-batch-eh) which will retry the whole batch and optionally send it to a dead letter topic.

In either case, use a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` in the error handler and DON'T enable DLQ in the binder.

Comment: Thanks for your response Gary. I ended up using `ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>> listenerContainerCustomizer(KafkaOperations<Integer, String> template)` . Interestingly that template doesn't appear to have the correct brokers set. It seems to just use default to localhost:9092 rather then reading properties from the config files?

Comment: If you are using Boot's auto-configured template, it knows nothing about spring-cloud-stream so it uses the boot properties `spring.kafka...`; spring-cloud-stream will also use those properties as the base before applying binder, then binding, properties.

Comment: I was able to successfully handle exceptions within the listener and send the DLQ etc. But now I need to handle deserialization exceptions that occur in the consumer. Have updated question with details of what I've tried. The problem seems to be sending a BadRequestEvent to the listener which is expecting a RequestEvent which results in the extra information in the BadRequestEvent being lost during the serialization

Comment: `>But when this is finally sent to the listener it is being serilaized back into RequestEvent and the information is lost.` That makes no sense to me. We have a test case [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/main/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/BatchListenerConversion2Tests.java#L153-L164) that receives a list of `Foo`s with a `BadFoo` in it.